# Is there a graphical intuition behind the Vieta's substitution for reduction of a depressed cubic to a quadratic?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

Like for the first substitution from a general cubic equation to a depressed cubic, a substitution is made so that the inflection point of the cubic equation changes to the y axis, so that it represents a depressed cubic, similarly is there a graphical institution for Vieta's sub ($x=w-\frac{p}{3w}$ for $x^3 + px+q=0$)?
One of the ways I know the sub was thought of was to just convert into a "perfect cube" but I think it's more algebra sided and would like a more visual approach.

Comment: hi! I wanted a more "graphical" insight.

Comment: I praise graphical explanations in general but here it looks a purely algebraic reasoning/intuition.

Comment: I understand, thank you!